# iOS: CollectionView with image error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I created a Collection View on my View, and now I'm trying to insert a image on the cell:
But, the screen stay black.
I saw that the code: `UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];` is returning nil. What is the problem?

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath; {
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ic_see_on_map.png"];

    return cell;

     }
```

Comment: you cell is not nil in the `viewWithTag` line?

Comment: Are you sure there is a UIImageView in the cell with the tag 100?

Comment: I created a .xib called "Cell". And on this file I have a Collection view Cell with ImageView inside. Both are with tag 100.

Comment: you can iterate cell.subviews and print the tag of every subview to confirm whether there is the UIImageView with 100, maybe there is something wrong in your XIB.

Comment: Now, is returning imageView, but when I try to setImage I get this error: -[UICollectionViewCell setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xad59980'

Comment: emm, can you remove the cell's 100 tag? You have gotten a cell then cast to UIImageView.

Comment: Remove from .xib? Sorry, didn't understand.

Comment: i mean you only set UIImageView'tag to 100, not the UICollectionViewCell's tag. I'm guessing the 'UIImageView' you get is not the UIImageView object.

Comment: Ok, u're right. I have to set the collectionview to 100 in code? How can I do this?

Comment: just now you said, you set both UICollectionViewCell and UIImageView's tags to 100 in XIB. Just set only UIImageView.

Comment: How about you create a custom cell class and assign it to the `UICollectionViewCell` in the storyboard and wire up the elements in the `UICollectionViewCell` (in storyboard) to the custom cell and use an object of the custom cell in your `UICollectionViewController`. This way you can be 100% sure about each and every element inside your  custom `UICollectionViewCell` and no need to use `viewWithTag`.

Comment: Alternatively, you can even add elements dynamically inside your collection view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the `UICollectionViewCell` and `UIImageView`' tags to 100 in your cell XIB. then  `UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];` will return the `UICollectionViewCell`. Then you cast a `UICollectionViewCell` object to `UIImageView` object. that's the problem. You need reset the `UICollectionViewCell`'s tag to 0 or whatever not 100. Then  you can get the `UIImageView` with tag 100.

Comment: How do I reset the UICollectionViewCell's tag? On xib?

Comment: Setting the Cell to tag 0 fixed for me! Thanks!

Comment: I have just the same piece of code of @Lücks, I did set imageView to 100 and Cell was 0, but I still getting imageView equal to nil when I try to retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you extract cell using cellForItemAtIndexPath and then traverse its hierarchy for imageview. Using tags is not advised as multiple cell's image views will get the same tag value which renders viewWithTag useless. Secondly you said screen stays black, are you able to see any cells of collection view or not? because than it means your collection view itself is not getting instantiated. To reset tag is to go to nib and set tag property to 0.

Comment: I tested using a .XIB with a collectionviewcell and a label. So, I could see the label. Then, I changed for a uimageview, but now I'm getting this error